# LINQ multiple and or condition

Tags: c#, linq

Im having trouble with my multiple AND/OR LINQ query

Current Error is `"&& cannot be applied to bool and datetime"`

Is there a better way to do this? 
I think I may need to check for nulls on some of those too

Thanks

```
(d.Development != 1 && d.Deleted != 1 && d.Stock != 1) && (d.DecommissionDate = Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01"))
```

Comment: Should be `(d.DecommissionDate == Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01")`

Comment: which if DecommissionDate is Null, i need that in there too... Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second part doesn't convert to a boolean:

```
(d.DecommissionDate = Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01"))
```

`=` is an assignment operator. When it is done, it will try to compare a boolean to a `DateTime`. If your intent is to compare the `DecommissionDate`, use `==` instead. If you really want to assign it, you need to do it on a separate occasion.

Answer (score 2):

You got a small typo: you used the single equals (`=`, used for assignment) instead of the double equals (`==`, equality).

Here's the fix:

```
d.DecommissionDate == Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01")
```